# Не работают стили css

Tags: html, css

*Всем привет, столкнулся с очень простой , но с проблемой которая меня уже мучает уже месяц , а то и больше...*

В общем проблема заключается в том , что я не могу использоваться css код который я пишу в файле main.css , хотя прежний код работает и отображает страницу, а тот что я изменяю , верстаю он игнорируется, хотя если прописать тоже самое но в файле index.php ( просто в тегах  ) , так всё сразу работает , ошибок в консоле и предупреждений нет, подключения указаны все правильно , проверил. Подскажите, что делать?Может кто-то с этим сталкивался?

Вот мой сайт на котором происходят траблы: [ТЫК](https://stell-team.ru/)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй на вкладке с сайтом нажать **ctrl+F5**

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/405282)

Comment: @nörbörnën, ну в принципе это решение. Хотя и половинчатое.

Answer (score 1):

Во время разработки, чтобы не мучатся с кешем, вы можете передавать к подключаемым файлам дополнительный параметр, по типу ?v=12 (называйте как хотите).

Чтобы сбросить кеш, достаточно будет просто поменять цифру(в моем примере) и кеш сбросится.

Пример:

```
<script src="/assets/main.js?v=12"></script>
```

Если используете PHP, достаточно вообще при каждой загрузке подставлять туда временную метку, и ручками делать вообще ничего не придется, при каждой загрузке будет "актуальная" версия файла

```
<script src="/assets/main.js?v=<?=time()?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ДА я сталкивался с такой проблемой, дело в кэширование страницы
Попробуй добавить это в html

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

если не помогло попробуй это

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

и если это тоже не помогло то в php

```
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

и если все это не помогло добавь вот это в конец .htaccess

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: А что делать если вообще ничего не помогло?

Comment: Всё не нужно я решил проблему по другому , просто очистите кеш браузера

Comment: это не поможет скоро это все повториться если не исользовать выше написанное

Comment: Жесть какая, достаточно просто в конце подключаемых файлов добавить ?v=2. Пример: src="main.js?v=2", и достаточно просто изменить цифру чтобы сбросить кеш

Comment: и так с каждым файлом если подключить а я на все говорю, чтоб файлы не менялись, может в скрипте где то еще используеться этот файл. на каждом месте зачем менять если можно просто запретить кэширование

Comment: если это все не помогло значить попробуй файлы  как ранее сказали         <script src="/assets/main.js?v=<?=time()?>"></script>